# Change Default Date Format in Console Log

Tags: javascript, date, console.log

How can I change the `console.log(x)` result modifying only the Browser, the Javascript environment or the console call, when printing a `Date` value, or a date array, independently of where that value appear?

With `console.log(x)`:

```
Date Wed May 05 2021 21:13:43 GMT-0000 (Standard Time)
```

The format i would like to have for Date arrays (same that `.toISOString()`),

```
2021-05-05T21:13:43.000Z
```

Comment: You can create your own function, or override `log`. The former seems easier, but without seeing your input and expected output it's harder to say.

Comment: Your title asks about the default Date format, you've tagged the question with the [date] tag, but your question body asks about arrays. Also, you get a preview when you're asking the question; take as much time as you need getting the question right there, rather than making people reload the question every minute...

Comment: I always suggest people use `console.log(JSON.stringify(x, null, 2))` when sharing an object's state and here it is no different.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways of doing this. The first is simply to map your array of `Date` objects to an array of strings:

```js
var x = [new Date()];
console.log(x.map(d => d.toISOString()));
```

Another way, which I find much easier, is to use `JSON.stringify`:

```js
var x = [new Date()];
console.log(JSON.stringify(x, null, 2));
```

Comment: This do shows the array elements in the format, and solves the direct problem I had. What I am looking for is some way to change the default format for Date, which are shown in all the console calls when showing a Date, regardless of where that datatype appear. Take any array for example, when showing it in the console, it highlights it as array, with the length, coloured, and with a format.

Comment: It you always use `JSON.stringify`, you can override the Date's `toJSON` function to change its its formatting. Changing its color and all that, that's a whole different thing. You'd have to override `console.log` altogether and recreate everything it does natively, much like the console for Stack Snippets does. That's a bit more time and effort than I'm willing to put in for free, plus there are many libraries out there (do a search for "console.log replacements").

Comment: Easier? The *JSON.stringify* example is exactly the same number of characters as the *map* example. :-)